# Difference between '%{}', '%Q{}', '%q{}' in ruby string delimiters

Tags: ruby, string

I was going through an online tutorial on ruby and found this "General Delimited Strings",

```
%{a word}  # => "a word"
%Q{a word} # => "a word"
%q{a word} # equivalent to single quoted version.
```

so i tried it on irb and this is what i see

```
2.0.0p247 :025 > %Q(hi)
 => "hi" 
2.0.0p247 :026 > %q(the)
 => "the" 
2.0.0p247 :027 > %q(th"e)
 => "th\"e" 
2.0.0p247 :028 > %q(th'e)
 => "th'e" 
2.0.0p247 :029 > %Q(h'i)
 => "h'i" 
2.0.0p247 :030 > %Q(h"i)
 => "h\"i"
```

Both %q and %Q behave the same and takes string in double quotes. Anybody know what exactly the use of these 2 if we can use %{} to get the same output.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Here is some hints about them [`Ruby_Programming - The % Notation`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#The_.25_Notation):

> %Q[ ] - Interpolated String (default)
>
> %q[ ] - Non-interpolated String (except for \ , [ and ])

Example :

```
x = "hi"
p %Q[#{x} Ram!] #= > "hi Ram!"
p %q[#{x} Ram!] #= > "\#{x} Ram!"
p %Q[th\e] #= > "th\e"
p %q[th\e] #= > "th\\e" # notice the \\ with %q[]
```

Another good resource [`Percent Strings`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Percent+Strings)

> Besides `%(...)` which creates a String, The `%` may create other types of object. As with strings, an uppercase letter allows interpolation and escaped characters while a lowercase letter disables them.

Comment: Interesting to note... Any symbol can be used as the delimiter, not just the square brackets, and space can be used as well (but don't).

Comment: [RuboCop recommends using parentheses `%(...)` for string literals](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#percent-literal-braces)

Answer (score 20):

`%q(no interpolation)`

`%Q(interpolation and backslashes)`

`%(interpolation and backslashes)`

**Example**

```
$ str = 'sushant'

$ %q[#{str} "mane"]
 => "\#{str} \"mane\""

$ %Q[#{str} "mane"]
 => "sushant \"mane\""

$ %[#{str} "mane"]
 => "sushant \"mane\""
```

Answer (score 2):

%{}, %Q{} and %q{} are for sure not different ways to write the same thing.

%{} transforms whatever is in curly brackets {} to a string.

%Q{} and %q{} both transform what is inside curly brackets into a string but Q puts the string in double quotes "" and q into single quotes ''.

So, the actual question is what the difference between "" and '' in Ruby. Basically, the '' do not allow interpolation or character escaping while "" do.

What does this mean? If I have a variable

```
one = 1
```

and I write

```
puts %q{#{one}}
puts %Q{#{one}}
```

when I run the script I will get:

```
>>>one
>>>1
```

Why?
In the first line q transforms one to 'one' so the # before has no use. In the second line Q transforms one to "one", so the #{one} means don't apply the rule that you were asked earlier to what is in the {} following the #. The rule that was applied earlier was the % that means make everything in the {} a string. Well, # now says do NOT make it a string.

But what is the use of applying a rule and then escaping it? In the {} brackets we can write many different things including quotes (single or double), strings and variables. Depending to what we want to print in the end, we have to choose which of the three will give us the results we want.