# Escaping in %q notation won't work in irb

Tags: ruby

Here is a sample code called test.rb:

```
s = %Q_abc\_def\_ghi_
puts s

s = %q_abc\_def\_ghi_
puts s
```

It works fine as expected:

```
➜  Desktop ruby test.rb
abc_def_ghi
abc_def_ghi
```

However, when I run it in irb, nothing happened after `s = %q_abc\_def\_ghi_`:

```
➜  Desktop irb
irb(main):001:0> s = %Q_abc\_def\_ghi_
=> "abc_def_ghi"
irb(main):002:0> puts s
abc_def_ghi
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> 
irb(main):004:0* s = %q_abc\_def\_ghi_
irb(main):005:1> puts s
irb(main):006:1> 
irb(main):007:1* 
irb(main):008:1*
```

Why it won't work? And how can I escape '_' (or other delimiters) in %q notation?

My Ruby version is:

```
ruby -v 
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin15]
```

Comment: I believe that `%q` does not recognize escape sequences. However, I am not sure why you don't just choose a different character `%q{abc_def_ghi_}` that does not require escaping

Comment: The reason why I choose `%q_abc\_def\_ghi_` is just for learning purpose. I understand `%q{abc_def_ghi_}` is natural. But I just want to know WHY.

Comment: Do try and paste in plain text input or output as plain text. Screenshots are difficult for some people to use.

Comment: Added plain text version.

Comment: @JunichiIto If the screenshot is redundant (not sure), maybe it could be removed for less information to worry about.

Comment: Okay, removed screenshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IRB has its own Ruby lexer/parser which it uses to try and keep track of the state of code entered so that it can do things like display different prompts depending on things like if you are in the middle of a string or defining a method or class. The code is the passed to Ruby to be evaluated “properly”.

It looks like this has a bug relating to how it handles escaping of single quoted style strings that aren’t actually using using single quotes.

Ruby itself handles the escaping just fine, so normally I don’t think this bug would actually have much affect, but in your example you happen to have used the string `def` right after the second `_`, which is a keyword that [IRB also looks for](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_4_0_preview1/lib/irb/ruby-lex.rb#L299).

This combination appears to put IRB into a strange state where its understanding of what is going on differs from what’s actually happening. This is the odd behaviour you are seeing.

A little playing around with a checked out version of the IRB code seems to support this. The [snippet I think is to blame looks like this](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_4_0_preview1/lib/irb/ruby-lex.rb#L1039-L1044):

```
elsif ch == '\\' and @ltype == "'" #'
  case ch = getc
  when "\\", "\n", "'"
  else
    ungetc
  end
```

Changing the `when` line to also look for the actual character being used:

```
when "\\", "\n", "'", quoted
```

(`quoted` is a parameter passed to the function) *appears* to fix it, and your examples all work fine with this modified version. I don’t know if that is a sufficient fix though, I don’t know the code—this is just a quick hack.

It might be worth opening a bug about this.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. I opened an issue: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12712

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this displays differently in your Ruby file and IRB but lowercase percent strings do not escape. See [Difference between '%{}', '%Q{}', '%q{}' in ruby string delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19782799/difference-between-q-q-in-ruby-string-delimiters)

Since `%q` does not support escaping, there is probably some undefined behavior when you try to use different delimiters and escape characters.

This probably isn't the answer you were looking for but I think it should help a bit.

Comment: Mmm, if `%q` does not support escaping, both ruby command and irb should give syntax error at `s = %q_abc\_def\_ghi_`. Very strange.