# How can I get a non-interpolation bash escape in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

In ruby, the backticks are a system call, but they are interpolation. This is nice as I could do this

```
a = 20.sqrt
`cat #{a}`
```

But it is also annoying because I sometimes want `\` in my code, but I need `\\` within ``` `` ``` because it is interpolation and escaping. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Kernel.`('echo "#{a}"')
```

Which prints verbatim

```
#{a}
```

Fun fact, `` ` `` is actually a method on `Kernel` and you can call it just like any other method. And thus pass a single quote string as argument.

Comment: Ahah. This method call looks so weird and unbalanced. I didn't know it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Form the string in a nonescaping context and interpolate it into the backticks:

```
s = %{echo "he\ny"}
puts `#{s}`
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need to juggle with escape characters, you could instead use %q :

```
system(%q{echo '#&%$][/\'})
#=> #&%$][/\
```

If you want string interpolation, you can use %Q :

```
a = 20
system(%Q{echo '#{a}&%$][/\'})
#=> 20&%$][/
```

Here's a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19782799/difference-between-q-q-in-ruby-string-delimiters) about it. Note that you can use any delimiter after `%q` and `%Q` : pick one that isn't in your string!

I used `system` here instead of `%x{}` or ticks. They're not equivalent, but I just wanted to show the string definition without making the line even more complex than it already is.

Comment: `system` differs from backtick though. It peints to stdout rather than capturing all output and returning it as string.

Comment: Sure. I didn't want to complicate the line any further. You're right though, I'll add a note