# string split('') issue in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In rails i tried string split('') but when i try on different string input output is different-

here is some test-
when i tried split on **1.1.split('')** output is okay-

```
1.1.to_s.split('')
# ["1", ".", "1"]
```

but when i tried on **1.1.1.split('')** error shown- 
how can i try split or count in such string like- 1.1.1 -

```
1.1.1.to_s.split('')
# syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input
```

Comment: How're you coming up with `1.1.1` (as a non string object)?

Comment: @SebastianPalma i have id Like 1.1.1 i applied .to_s to convert this as string . is i am doing wrong? i have find length of given input using what method i can find without any error

Comment: Try wrapping your id with parenthesis () and then apply to_s.split()

Comment: @Tushar tried but still i am getting error. ```(1.1.1).to_s.split('')```

Comment: Ruby parses `1.1` as `Number` but `1.1.1` doesn't fall into Ruby's grammar. So if you just type `1.1.1` in IRB console, you will notice it throwing syntax error.

Comment: @AmitPatel i am able to see error. but how can i convert this id to string and also count length?

Comment: how you get `1.1.1` in your code?

Comment: @AmitPatel ```(2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
        row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
       row['id'].to_s.split('').count == 5  end end``` here i get row['id'] when i import excel file.

Comment: What is the content type of your `row['id']` ?

Comment: @Dylandy content is not defined yet. just taking from id from excel file as - row['id']= 1.1.1

Comment: `.to_s` converts an object to a string. `1.1.1` however is not a valid Ruby literal. Maybe you mean `'1.1.1`'? In that case, you don't need `to_s` because your object already is a string. Try `row['id'].class` and you'll see the object's class. (it's probably `String`)

Comment: @rock : You can see from your error message, which clearly says **syntax error**, that `split` is not even invoked in this case, so the way you ask the question, is meaningless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby does not support barewords strings. In order to create a string literal you need to quote it with single or double quotes or use [%q/%Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19782799/difference-between-q-q-in-ruby-string-delimiters).

```
row['id']= "1.1.1" # interpolated
row['id']= '1.1.1' # non-interpolated
row['id']= %Q{1.1.1} # interpolated - useful when dealing with strings with quotes
row['id']= %q{1.1.1} # like above but non-interpolated
```

Comment: `1.1.1` is not a valid IP address. (also it's `row['id']`, not `row['ip']`)

Comment: You're right @Stefan I have remove the part about IpAddr.

Comment: Note that the result of the percent strings is not the same as that of the normal string. The spaces you've added in them will be in the string contents. `%q{ 1.1.1 } == '1.1.1' #=> false`

Comment: @3limin4t0r that was an omission on my part. Thanks.